# How to returns a list of all values corresponding to keys greater than x in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to use for For loop to find the return the list of values in a dictionary greater than x.

```
d= {}
for key in d():
    if key > x:
        return(d(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

We hold greater_than_x list, and append the values in d dictionary if it's bigger than the given x.

```
x = 20
greater_than_x = []
d = {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30}


for value in d.values():
    if value > x:
        greater_than_x.append(value)

print(greater_than_x)

>[30]
```

One-liner applying the same logic:

```
x = 20
d = {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30}

greater_than_x = [value for value in d.values() if value > x]
print(greater_than_x)

>[30]
```

Comment: Why even iterate over keys? Why not `for value in d.values()` directly?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict(a=1, b=10, c=30, d=2)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 30, 'b': 10, 'd': 2}   

d = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v >= 10)
>>> d    
{'c': 30, 'b': 10}

values_list = list(d.values())
>>> values_list
[30, 10]
```